# Necessity of NoSQL database testing

Tags: rest, couchbase, database-testing, nosql

I have a web server application using Couchbase Server as its backend database.
Application comprises of few set of REST API's.

Now I have tested all my REST API's properly and deeply for all the scenarios, now I am in a dilemma if I should test my DB separately or not.

Because my REST API's gave me correct response (from DB) for all my input's passed to them. 
So is there a need to separately test my DB using sql queries because it is the same thing which was done by API's.

And I am not considering the performance testing which is in my later scope. Just considering the functional testing.

Comment: There are some approaches for persistence unit testing like Acolyte framework (for JDBC & ReactiveMongo 0.10; http://acolyte.eu.org/ ). Something similar for CouchDB can be designed I guess.